# What's the difference between all these terms?

Tags: terminology, graphics

What's the difference between them - Physically based simulation, Physically based animation, Physical simulation for computer animation, Physically based animation for Computer graphics, Physically based modelling for interactive simulation and games and Cognitive modelling ?

Comment: What research have you done? Can you separate at least some of the notions?

Comment: http://www.google.com would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These terms are not precisely defined and may overlap, but I think the following are both useful and non-controversial:

- Physically based simulation: Simulation of some physical process, generally employing the laws of physics, for instance modeling of some combustion equations to find the temperature of a gas versus time.
- Physically based animation:  Simulation of some physical process, generally employing the laws of physics, in order to render a visual image of some process, such as creating a movie sequence of the bursting of a water balloon as it is pierced by a pin.
- Physical simulation for computer animation:  I believe this term is synonymous with "Physically based animation."
- Physically based animation for computer graphics:  I believe this term is synonymous with "Physically based animation."
- Physically based modelling for interactive simulation and games and cognitive modelling:  I believe this means the same as "Physically based animation," but is applied to computer games, not movies.